# Expo Google login working with Android simulator but not with iOS

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-ios

I am making a simple Expo app where i am trying to implement the Google and Facebook login. I have implemented Facebook login, and tested on Both iOS and Android.

But with Google login i tried but its only working with Android Simulator. Its not working with iOS device and Simulator.

My Links are correct. But its giving me problem only with iOS simulator. This code is working with Android simulator and giving me google token on andorid device. But on iOS i am getting this error

```
"Your app is missing support for the following URL schemes com.googleusercontent.apps.ID-googleGivenID" was thrown while invoking loginAsync on target ExponentGoogle with params({ androidClientId = #ID-googleGivenID.apps.googleusercontent.com;
behaviour = system;
iosClientId = "#ID-googleGivenID.apps.googleusercontent.com";
scopes = (
  profile,
  email
)
})
```

> App.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "InStore",
    "description": "This project is really great.",
    "slug": "InStore",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "31.0.0",
    "platforms": ["ios", "android"],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "extra": {
      "googleAppId": {
        "ios": "#ID-googleGivenID.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        "android": "#ID-googleGivenID.apps.googleusercontent.com"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> Google Login File

```
const loginAsync = async () => {
  try {
    const result = await Google.logInAsync({
      androidClientId: '#ID-googleGivenID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      iosClientId: '#ID-googleGivenID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      scopes: ['profile', 'email']
    });

    if (result.type == 'success') {
      return Promise.resolve(result.accessToken);
    } else {
      return Promise.reject('Filed');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed with

```
behavior : 'web' 
const result = await Expo.Google.logInAsync({ iosClientId: '-------------.apps.googleusercontent.com', androidClientId: '--------.apps.googleusercontent.com', behavior: 'web', scopes: ['profile', 'email'], });
```